# Dagger 2 modules depending on each other

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have a couple of classes that depend on each other, `GamePresenter` and `GameManager`.
I'm trying to inject them using constructor injection, but I still can't figure out how to make it work, since I got a dependency cycle error found.

`GameFragment` should inject the `GamePresenter` into the fragment, so the first would talk to the second, while `GameManager` would be injected into the `GamePresenter`.

`GamePresenter` is:

```
@Inject
GamePresenter(GameRepository gameRepository, GameManager gameManager, GameContract.View view) {
    DaggerGameManagerComponent.builder()
            .gameManagerModule(new GameManagerModule(this))
            .build()
            .inject(this);

    this.view = view;
    this.gameRepository = gameRepository;
    this.gameManager = gameManager;
}
```

`GamePresenterModule` is:

```
@Module
public class GamePresenterModule {
    private final GameContract.View view;

    public GamePresenterModule(GameContract.View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Provides
    GameContract.View provideGameContractView() {
        return view;
    }
}
```

`GamePresenterComponent` is:

```
@FragmentScoped
@Component(dependencies = RepositoryComponent.class, modules = GamePresenterModule.class)
public interface GamePresenterComponent {
    void inject(GameFragment gameFragment);
}
```

`GameManager` is:

```
@Inject
public GameManager(GamePresenter gamePresenter, Game game) {
    this.gamePresenter = gamePresenter;
    this.game = game;
}
```

`GameManagerModule` is:

```
@Module
public class GameManagerModule {
    private GamePresenter presenter;

    public GameManagerModule(GamePresenter presenter) {
        this.presenter = presenter;
    }

    @Provides
    GameManager provideGameManager(Game game) {
        return new GameManager(this.presenter, game);
    }

    @Provides
    Game provideGame() {
        return new Game();
    }
}
```

`GameManagerComponent` is:

```
@FragmentScoped
@Component(dependencies = GamePresenterComponent.class, modules = GameManagerModule.class)
public interface GameManagerComponent {
    void inject(GamePresenter gamePresenter);
}
```

and finally, `GameFragment` is:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);

    DaggerGamePresenterComponent.builder()
            .repositoryComponent(((GameApplication) getActivity().getApplication()).getRepositoryComponent())
            .gamePresenterModule(new GamePresenterModule(this))
            .build()
            .inject(this);
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should overthink your architecture when you have this kind of issues.

In this case I'd suggest to not inject the `GameManager` into the `GamePresenter`. Instead define an interface with whatever methods you need from `GameManager`, let the `GameManager` be implemented it and register it inside the constructor or provider.

Comment: how can I do that? specially the "register it inside the constructor or provider"